# Apply the unique constraint to combinations of columns in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-design, constraints

I have a table called product_attributes in a `MySQL` Database.  It consists of a product SKU (foreign key), an attribute label and an attribute value.  I need to ensure that combinations of SKU and attribute labels are unique.

### EXAMPLE -

**inserting this would be** *legal*

```
{001, 'weight', '100 lbs'}
{001, 'color', 'blue'}
{002, 'weight', '200 lbs'}
```

**This would be** *illegal*

```
{001, 'weight', '100 lbs'}
{001, 'weight', '200lbs' }
```

---

-How can enforce this constraint?
-Do I have to do this in my server-side language or can I configure my database to enforce this?
-What is this type of constraint called?

Comment: Oh you're in in for such a huge world of hurt. What if a product could come in two colors? or two sizes. What you've built is called an EAV or Entity Attribute Value model and you can't think of a worse model for relational data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679376/database-design-question/3680163#3680163

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Haven't tested this but the DDL (Data Definition Language) for adding a Unique key is

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD CONSTRAINT UniqueSkuAttribKey UNIQUE (SKU, Attribute)
```

Primary key is

```
ALTER TABLE foo
ADD CONSTRAINT PrimaryFooKey Primary (SKU, Attribute)
```

Comment: upvote cause you beat me by minutes. i should learn to reload before typing :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a unique constraint on the two rows

```
ALTER TABLE product_attributes ADD CONSTRAINT unique_sku_attribute UNIQUE (sku, attribute);
```

edit: reworded from unique index to unique constraint. oops

Answer (score 3):

You can either make `ProductSKU` and `AttributeLabel` a composite PK, or put a unique constraint on them. Either will achieve your purpose. You may wish to use a surrogate key for convenience (or because your model layer requires it), in which case the unique constraint is the way to go.

Typically you will still need code to handle exceptions in your applications, regardless of what you do with the database.