# DB design help - EAV + Form builder

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm trying to build a sort of form builder that'll allow me to define, display and store 'tests' in a flexible way. I.e. Allow the user, through the web interface, to create a new type of test/form ("Grouping") and define a set of fields that will be displayed on the form (any type of field, including date, text, radio, checkbox, etc). I'll also need a results table that'll store the values saved in each form/test.

As an inadequate example, I have the following 3 tables so far:

```
dd_TestGrouping
- TestGroupingID [pk]  
- TestGroupingName  "Algebra-1"
- TestGroupingTypeID "Math"

dd_TestFields
- TestFieldID [pk]
- TestGroupingID [fk]
- TestFieldName "Circumference"
- TestFieldType "TextBox"
- Sequence

TestResults
- TestResultID [pk]
- TestFieldID [fk]
- value "50"
- Unit "CM"
```

The problem with the above - if nothing else - I'm not sure how to dynamically display dropdown lists and linked radio/checkboxes. Also, how can I handle validation?

Thanks in advance for any help/pointers.

Comment: Please read my answer before setting of on your EAV journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like this would be a good case for using an [EAV model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).

Comment: The tables in the OPs question already are an example of the EAV model.

Comment: Thanks, knowing what it's called helped me find tons of help - it is indeed EAV and - based on what I've read so far - the right choice (for health records).

Comment: Wait, (Health records)? Didn't you say algebra tests?

Comment: Yes, I did - explanation commented on your post below (I am dealing with health records).

Answer (score 4):

To include combo box values you need to extend your model via something like this:

```
dd_TestFields
- TestFieldID [pk]
- TestGroupingID [fk]
- TestFieldName "Gender"
- TestFieldType "Combo Box"
- Sequence
```

with a new table:

```
dd_TestFieldSelection
- TestFieldSelectioniD [pk]
- TestFieldID [fk]
- TestFieldValue "Female"
- Sequence
```

Validation i think naturally belongs in your dd_TestFields table:

```
dd_TestFields
- TestFieldID [pk]
- TestGroupingID [fk]
- TestFieldName "Age"
- TestFieldType "Number/Text Box"
- Sequence
- Required "True"
- MinValue "0"
- MaxValue "150"
```

This is just a rough sketch but you can extend the ideas as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

first, beware of the [inner platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

second, supporting dropdowns is just a matter of having a 4th table which includes all the possible values for a "multi" type of field.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so in your answers and comments you've described two very different scenarios.

If it's a form builder for algebra tests and described in your sample then please read 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679376/database-design-question/3680163#3680163). The EAV is very seductive but you will pay a massive price for using a normal RDBMS to construct that model.

However,

If it's health records as you say in a comment. That's a different ballgame. Health records are bizarre because there's essentially a limitless number of symptoms and significant lack of symptoms. Say you have a surgical wound and you spike a fever. That could indicate an infection. If there's no redness, swelling, tenderness or draining puss from the wound, that would be the significant absence of a symptom.

Think of health records like Facebook. When you visit a friend's page, the database has the PK for that person and then gets everything by that. You don't normally do a count of users by hometown and are married for example. That query is a pain against an EAV. Same with health records. Patient 123 shows up, you just need his/her chart. You don't need to query everyone who share 6 symptoms. (BTW, that does happen in research but those EAV records would have to be filtered, pivoted and converted to a more 3nf format.)

If you are doing health records, I would look into some new EAV RDBMS being designed specifically for health records.

Comment: Apologies for the different examples. I am actually working on health records and only gave the math example initially as it seemed easier to explain. That said, though I'm working on health records, I have a slightly more defined set of data that I'm looking for. The main reason I was leaning towards the EAV pattern was because though there are a known set of tests (labs/diagnostics/physicals/etc), each hospital/department seems to capture them slightly different than the next. As such, I wanted to use EAV to easily customize the display and capture of tests based on hospital and department.

Comment: Also, I should add that it's not uncommon to add new types of tests (as a grouping) or fields within a test every few months.

Comment: It's always better to tell us what you're actually doing. A slight deviation can change the answer 180 degrees.

Comment: Like I said. EAV makes sense for health records. When you say "different hospitals capture them slightly differently", so you're going to sell this as a SaaS offering? You want to build a multi-tenant SaaS app?

Comment: That's right...it's a web based SaaS app starting with 3 sites with plans to expand to others. So it seems like EAV is the best way to go for the clinical results then. Thank you for the feedback.