# Help with modeling EAV in SQL/NoSQL mix (Sql server/RavenDB)

Tags: sql, sql-server, nosql, data-modeling, ravendb

I'm designing a health SaaS app and would appreciate some help with the initial modeling. I started with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247883/db-design-help-form-builder) to confirm that I should be using EAV at all - the answer was yes due to the sparsity of clinical data. I then started looking at possibly using a NoSQL option instead of trying to fit it into SQL. It seems a combination of the two would work best. I'll try to explain the requirement and my idea's and would love any feedback. I'm using .net.

**Requirement**
At the highest level, we have a 'Patient'. For a patient to need some medical help something would have happened, let's call that an "Incident". For each "Incident" a "Patient" can be seen multiple times, called "Visits". All clinical data (tests/history/etc) is stored per "Visit". So we have:

Patient 1 - ∞ Incidents 1 - ∞ Visits 1 - 1 Clinical data (many potential key/value pairs)

**Solution** (feedback would be great)

***SQL Tables***

```
Patient
- PatientID
- other patient info

Incident
- IncidentID
- PatientID
- Other incident info

Visit
- VisitID
- IncidentID
- Datetime
```

***NoSQL DocumentDB*** (probably RavenDB)

```
{ // Visit document - id: visits/12345
 "Patient": {
   "PatientId": "patients/54321",
   "Name": "John Smith"
 },
 "Incident": {
   "IncidentId": "incidents/55555",
   "Name": "Cardiac Arrest"
 },
 "VisitData": {
   "BP": "110/70",
   "Hypertension": "True"
   "Cardiac Disease": "Angina"
   "Stroke": "False"
   .... (could be tens or hundreds of key/value pairs)
 },

}
```

That's what I have so far. Aside from general opinions (all welcome), I was wondering if anyone thinks I should put all Incidents and Visits for each patient in ONE document as opposed to having one document per visit (which is what the above is supposed to be). I believe the documents could get 'too big' (without any idea of what too big means in a document based DB) and also almost always the views are based on a visit - though we'd need to show trending reports across visits as well.

Thanks in advance!!

Mike

Comment: Did you make noSQL and healthcare data work together somehow?. I just had the same question.

Answer (score 0):

this looks appropriate according to your stated requirements.

I think there is probably something else going on, which is maybe 'Condition' that is not necessarily part of any patient Incident.  For instance a person with Hypertension may simply have that condition when they present for a broken finger.

Also, Incident may be hard to define - is it a single point in time event or is it a progressive duration of deterioration?  Maybe this means Incident is really just a marker on a visit, or maybe you have a visit to vist association table that lets you declare that a visit is a followup to another visit, building a hierarchy or netwrok of the care a patient received.

just a couple thoughts off the top.. hth

edit - afterthought:  I would for sure recommend a SQL db with properly normalized tables...

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I left out one piece which we call medical history/risk factors which are only associated with the Patient and not to any Incident or Visit - I didn't want to overcomplicate the post, but I would have a separate document in the NoSql db for the said records as they are also a potentially wide and sparse variety of fields.

Comment: Are you saying you recommend to do all of it in a SQL db? What about the sparsity issue? There could potentially thousands of data points for each patient but most likely no patient would have more than 10% of them, if that much, tested/used. In a SQL db we'd need a column for every one of those potential data points even if they'll mostly be null.

Comment: it sounds like the thinking should be flipped.  instead of a 'column' for each of thousands of items, those should be 'rows', then you would only get a row if needed.

Comment: That would be the EAV model, correct? That's what I was planning to do at first, but it seemed to make more sense to put just that part in a document based DB instead. Using EAV in SQL you're basically losing all the advantages of a sql db anyway (no referential integrity, cardinality, etc).

Comment: it doesnt have to be EAV (which i agree has limitations).  I'm basically just describing a normalization where say procedure codes are in one table, and then those are associated to the patient through a visit_procedure table or something... then you do not need a column for each procedure possible with a check mark for which ones the patient got but instead just a row to indicate that procedure was perfrmed on that patient during that visit.  If you need a new procedure, then add a row to the procedure table and begin using it as a referenced item, as opposed to adding a new column somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

a mix of databases may work best. Existing appraches use EAV but the problem is with nested facts - alert about drug interaction could be  master event in a SQL table

but then how severe alert, to whom sent, which 2 drugs - those details can go to a document-based noSQL db.